# IPv6 LAN Clients IPV6 Address List

Tags: linux, ipv6

I am only using `'radvd'[Stateles Addres Configuration]` server to advertise the prefix for LAN clients. LAN clients are formaing global ipv6 address based on advertised prefix.

I need to display the IPV6 global addresses of the LAN clients in the device(router).
How I can get the global v6 addresses of the LAN clients?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what make and model router you have.

This is how to find this information on Linux, if this is helpful(?).
To see neighbor cache run this:

```
ip -6 neigh show
```

I believe this shows just link local addresses.

Pinging the all hosts multi-cast address will list the global scope IPv6 addresses on the LAN.

```
ping6 -I <your-global-ipv6> ff02::1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the devices use autoconfiguration to configure themselves there is no central server that knows about all the clients. Radvd only sends out information about the network, it doesn't negotiate with the clients.

If you want to keep track of the clients on your network you can use tools like [ndpmon](http://ndpmon.sourceforge.net/) that monitor Neighbour Discovery (which does what ARP used to do for IPv4)